# How to model a simple shoe

Tags: modeling

I want to model a shoe more like a foot without fingers. Can anyone show me how to model like this[image]

Answer (score 4):

Create a cube, scale it, create some loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

[image]

Begin to move the vertices, edges and faces, use the *Proportional Editing* option:

[image]

Delete a vertex to cut a hole:

[image]

Extrude inwards and right click > LoopTools > Circle:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Comment: +1 of course ...mr. shoe...äh...moonboots is the right man for this task!!!

Comment: @Chris, exactly, I'm good at modeling shoes, boots, moons, etc

Comment: no you aren't. You are basically good at modeling.....anything!

Comment: @Chris, thanks Chris, I try I try  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to @moonboots excellent answer that if you add a subdivision surface modifier you can create a smooth looking version very easily:

[image: Shoe without subdivision modifier]

[image: Shoe with subdivision modifier]